# Selecting parent to use `:not()` operator without child element is possible?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply color only parent level, by using `:not()` operator. but no result. is it possible?

html:

```
<header>title <span>123</span></header>
```

CSS:

```css
header:not(header span){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>title <span>123</span></header>
```

```
header:not(header span){
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Your selector is targeting `header` not `span`, so `header` will either be green, or not. You need a second rule for `span`.

Comment: Do you have to use the :not() operator?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two css rules, one specifically targeting the span to unset the `color: green` rule applied by the header css rule.

```css
header {
  color: green;
}

header span {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<header>title <span>123</span></header>
```

Comment: this is not addressing the `:not()` selector